# Testing Pagination Methods and Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view-helpers

Ok, I have some objects (which really don't matter here), and I added \ pagination methods and heplers. Now I want to test how it looks, and how it works.
The problem is what I want to check out it for 10,20 and so on number of pages. But it is really time-consuming to create this many of objects, which to paginate, to test this?
Are there any other options?

EDIT:the trick is that there are compex validations including uniqueness, so I can't just write a loop in console from 1 to 200 for example to create needed amount of objects.

Comment: Are you using will_paginate gem?

Comment: no, just made it from scratch